# Errors with getting last known location using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) tutorial. Code I have:

```
package com.b.a;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class M extends AppCompatActivity {

        private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
        public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        public GoogleApiClient mLastLocation;
        private GoogleApiClient mLatitudeText;
        private GoogleApiClient mLongitudeText;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
      mLastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
           mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
          mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

}
```

Sorry if this is noobish, but I don't know what's wrong. `setText()`, `getLongitude()` and `getLatitude()` aren't recognized. `addConnectionCallback`'s `this` in Builder can't be applied, and there's an incompatible types error with `onConnected (Bundle..)`. I used the map activity option when creating the new project. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide exact error messages (ex. The message that is telling you that setText() isn't recognized)

Comment: I decided to start over. I created a new blank activity. Then, I went right to the tutorial. I put the `permission` line under `manifest`, but not `package`, since I think that's the name of their app, and I'm not using the same name. I then put the `bulidGoogleApiClient` method in the `onCreate` method, but it still gives a Cannot resolve symbol error for GoogleApiClient and LocationServices. I put `GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;` right under `public class M extends AppCompatActivity`, but it didn't solve it.